# Why can't I move the images?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

For some reason the images just wont move when I click on them even though the same program worked on my laptop.

I want to be able to click on an image and then click to a blank square and move the image, but when I click on a blank square after I clicked on an image the image stays in place. I'm kind of new at coding and this website so sorry about any mistakes

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import string
    import os, sys
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
    
    
    class Board(tk.Frame):
    
        def __init__(self, parent, length, width):  # self=Frame, parent=root
    
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.length = length
            self.width = width
            self.config(height=100 * self.length, width=100 * self.width)
            self.pack()
    
            self.square_color = None
            self.squares = {}
            self.ranks = string.ascii_lowercase
            self.white_images = {}  # stores images of pieces
            self.white_pieces = ["image1", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7"]
            self.black_pieces = None
            self.buttons_pressed = 0
            self.turns = 0
            self.sq1 = None  # first square clicked
            self.sq2 = None
            self.sq1_button = None  # button associated with the square clicked
            self.sq2_button = None
            self.piece_color = None
            self.set_squares()
    
        def select_piece(self, button):  # called when a square button is pressed, consists of majority of the movement code
            if button["image"] in self.white_pieces == 0:  # checks color of first piece
                self.piece_color = "white"
                if self.buttons_pressed == 0:  # stores square and button of first square selected
                    self.sq1 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
                    self.sq1_button = button
                    self.buttons_pressed += 1
    
                elif self.buttons_pressed == 1:  # stores square and button of second square selected
                    self.sq2 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
                    self.sq2_button = button
                    if self.sq2 == self.sq1:  # prevents self-destruction and allows the user to choose a new piece
                        self.buttons_pressed = 0
                        return
    
                    if True:  # makes sure the move is legal
                        self.squares[self.sq2].config(image=self.sq1_button["image"])
                        self.squares[self.sq2].image = self.sq1_button["image"]
                        self.squares[self.sq1].config(image=self.white_images["blank.png"])  # clears sq1
                        self.squares[self.sq1].image = self.white_images["blank.png"]
                        self.sq1_button = self.squares[self.sq1]
                        self.buttons_pressed = 0
                        return
            else:
                self.buttons_pressed = 0
                return
    
        def set_squares(self):  # fills frame with buttons representing squares
    
            for x in range(5):
                for y in range(5):
                    b = tk.Button(self, bg=self.square_color, activebackground="lawn green")
                    b.grid(row=8 - x, column=y)
                    pos = self.ranks[y] + str(x + 1)
                    self.squares.setdefault(pos, b)  # creates list of square positions
                    self.squares[pos].config(command=lambda key=self.squares[pos]: self.select_piece(key))
    
        def import_pieces(self):  # opens and stores images of pieces and prepares the pieces for the game for both sides
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "white")  # stores white pieces images into dicts
            w_dirs = os.listdir(path)
            for file in w_dirs:
                img = Image.open(path + "/" + file)
                img = img.resize((80, 80), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
                self.white_images.setdefault(file, img)
    
        def set_pieces(self):  # places pieces in starting positions
            dict_rank1_pieces = {"a1": "dirt.png", "b1": "fire.png", "c1": "metal.png", "d1": "water.png", "e1": "wood.png"}
    
            for key in dict_rank1_pieces:  # inserts images into buttons
                starting_piece = dict_rank1_pieces[key]
                self.squares[key].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
                self.squares[key].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]
    
            for rank in range(2, 6):  # fill rest with blank pieces
                for file in range(5):
                    starting_piece = "blank.png"
                    pos = self.ranks[file] + str(rank)
                    self.squares[pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
                    self.squares[pos].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]
    
    
    root = tk.Tk()  
    root.geometry("800x800")
    board = Board(root, 5, 5)
    board.import_pieces()
    board.set_pieces()
    board.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post  the actual code as text. Also see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your `select_piece()` function has some flaws. Also without knowing your folder and file structure one can only guess what your code is supposed to do.

I assumed a folder structure like:

```
├── main.py
└── white
    ├── blank.png
    ├── dirt.png
    ├── fire.png
    ├── metal.png
    ├── water.png
    └── wood.png
```

The first flaw in your code, if you have the structure like me (which worked with your code) is the contents of `self.white_pieces = ["image1", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7"]` because the blank button you want to compare is called `"pyimage1"` and can therefore not be found. To check/debug ypou can `print(button["image"])` to the console to check what you are comparing.

*As a sidenote: You should really thing about naming conventions. Your names are often really confusing.*

The second flaw is that the first `if` only checks the color and not if it is the first or second button. So a second button can only be selected if it is blank too.

Lastly you get confused by changing the images of the button because you first set the second button (the one with the symbol) with the value of the first button (the blank one) and then the first (wich was already blank) as a blank image.

Here is my adaptation of your `select_piece()` function:

```py
def select_piece(self, button):
    # for me the white ones are pyimage1 and to check only the first button combine with buttons_pressed
    if button["image"] == "pyimage1" and self.buttons_pressed == 0:
        self.sq1 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
        self.sq1_button = button
        self.buttons_pressed = 1
    elif self.buttons_pressed == 1:
        self.sq2 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
        self.sq2_button = button
        # just return without changing pictures to select the second one again if move is illegal
        if self.sq2 == self.sq1:
            return
        # you only get here if the move is legal
        self.squares[self.sq1].config(image=self.sq2_button["image"])  # set first (blank) as second (icon)
        self.squares[self.sq1].image = self.sq2_button["image"]
        self.squares[self.sq2].config(image=self.white_images["blank.png"])  # set second (icon) as blank
        self.squares[self.sq2].image = self.white_images["blank.png"]
        self.sq1_button = self.squares[self.sq1]
        self.buttons_pressed = 0
```